# Oracle Coherence = Is this a library free of charge and can be used in my programm?

Tags: oracle-coherence

sorry for asking such a question:

But I was not able to figure out if the Coherence
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/downloads/coherence-101246.html
can be used in my programs.

Does anybody know what the licencing costs and if there is an "open/free" version that I can use in my programs free of charge? I know there are commercial editions available, but is there also a free edition available? (if not I think I will have to use infinispan?)

Thanks
Jens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle Coherence is covered by the OTN License. You can see the terms of the license at [OTN License Agreement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html). 
The license states the following:

> You may not:
>
> - use the programs for your own internal data processing or for any commercial or production purposes, or use the programs for any purpose except the development of your application;
> - use the application you develop with the programs for any internal data processing or commercial or production purposes without securing an appropriate license from us;
> - continue to develop your application after you have used it for any internal data processing, commercial or production purpose without securing an appropriate license from us, or an Oracle reseller;
> - remove or modify any program markings or any notice of our proprietary rights;
> - make the programs available in any manner to any third party;
> - use the programs to provide third party training;
> - assign this agreement or give or transfer the programs or an interest in them to another individual or entity; - cause or permit reverse engineering (unless required by law for interoperability), disassembly or decompilation of the programs;
> - disclose results of any program benchmark tests without our prior consent.*

---

You can view the prices at:

- [US Oracle Technology Commercial Price List (PDF)](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/technology-price-list-070617.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

No, Oracle Coherence cannot be used free of charge. It is a commercial product only. If you work for a large company, the company may already license it as part of a larger Oracle license agreement, for example as part of a WebLogic Suite license or something like that. If you work for a start-up, you may be able to get it for low cost or no charge for a period of time through an Oracle start-up program. If you work for a small or medium sized business, it will be very hard to get it, as the license is per-core (per "Oracle CPU") and the price is fairly high.

Answer (score 0):

[As 2020](https://medium.com/oracle-coherence/announcing-coherence-community-edition-297913cae433), there is now a free and open source version of Oracle Coherence, labeled as Community Edition.

GitHub project page: [oracle/coherence: Oracle Coherence Community Edition](https://github.com/oracle/coherence).